# Why am I getting a NameError which trying to run this For loop

Tags: python, pandas, salesforce

I am trying to access Salesforce through their API. I am trying to run the preliminary code but I get a NameError which doesn't make any sense to me at the moment.

This is my first time taking the previous developers code and trying to run it. I keep getting an error after error.

```py
l=[]
for p in products:
    query = 'SELECT '
    for c in columns[:-1]:
        query += c+','
    if (p=='Sigma Upgrade to Insight'):
        query += columns[-1] + ' FROM Implementation__c WHERE Imp_Type__c = \''+p+'\''
    else:
        query += columns[-1] + ' FROM Implementation__c WHERE Imp_Type__c INCLUDES (\''+p+'\') AND Implementation_Status__c != \'PE Trial Ended\''

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(sf.query(query))
    l.append(df_temp)

    runthrough = ('nextRecordsUrl' in df_temp.columns)
    while runthrough:
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(sf.query_more(nextRecord,True))
        l.append(df_temp)
        runthrough = ('nextRecordsUrl' in df_temp.columns)
```

I am expecting to run this without any errors but I keep getting a NameError

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7b44b14c79ff> in <module>
     14     runthrough = ('nextRecordsUrl' in df_temp.columns)
     15     while runthrough:
---> 16         df_temp = pd.DataFrame(sf.query_more(nextRecord,True))
     17         l.append(df_temp)
     18         runthrough = ('nextRecordsUrl' in df_temp.columns)

NameError: name 'nextRecord' is not defined
```

Comment: Where do you assign the variable `nextRecord`?

Comment: Indeed, `nextRecord` is *not* defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `nextRecord` to the value of the `nextRecordsUrl` element of `df_temp`.

```
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(sf.query(query))
    l.append(df_temp)

    while 'nextRecordsUrl' in df_temp.columns:
        nextRecord = df_temp['nextRecordsUrl']
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(sf.query_more(nextRecord,True))
        l.append(df_temp)
```